# jQuery returning undefined with transaction.executeSql()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to populate an html tag with data from a web sql database for a jqm application.  Here is my code:

```
 $("#profile").on("pageinit", function () {
    db.transaction(function (transaction) {
        var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile " +
            " (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "nickname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," +
            "tankVol VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," +
            "waterType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," +
            "category VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)"
        transaction.executeSql(sql, undefined);

        var sqlNickname = "SELECT nickname FROM profile";
        transaction.executeSql(sqlNickname, undefined, function (transaction, result) {
            var ul = "<ul>";
            if (result.rows.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = result.rows.item;
                    var nickname = row.nickname;
                    ul += "<li>" + nickname + "</li>";
                    ul += "</ul>";

                }
            }
            var $profileNickname = $("#profile div:jqmData(role=content)");
            $profileNickname.html(ul);
            var $nicknameContent = $profileNickname.find("ul");
            $nicknameContent.listview();
        }, error);
    });
});
```

The table I am using will always only have one record so I'm not sure that I need to iterate through the table with the for loop or not.  I believe the problem is int the line:

```
transaction.executeSql (sqlNickname, undefined,
```

because the table is working correctly and the html is being created correctly but in the list item element I am getting the string "undefined" instead of the value that is in the nickname column of the table.  Your help is appreciated!

Comment: At which point it returns undefined?  Do you mean `result` is undefined after second `executeSql` call?

Comment: The first executeSql call works... it creates a table.  The table is created correctly.  The problem occurs when using jquery to create a <li> with the value of the data contained in the nickname column.  What I am getting in the html is this <li>undefined</li>.  What I want is this <li>"value of nickname"</li>.  It doesn't have to be in a <li> element necessarily.  just need a method of taking that value and outputting it into html.  There is only one row in this table.  It gets overwritten each time the data is saved so I may not even need a for loop.

Comment: Wait, how do you put the data into the table?  Maybe you have a bug in that place?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are closing ur ul tag inside the loop.  If there are more then 1 entry in the resultset, you'll get several closing tags for one opening tag.  Place that closing tag outside the loop.

But the error you are getting is this:

```
var row = result.rows.item;
```

Change this to:

```
var row = result.rows.item(i);
```

So the program knows which row to take from your resultset.  Even for a single result this is necessary.